# OpenLayers 4 get southwest coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

I am migrating a map from google maps to openlayers, but I am having troubles with some functionalities.

The application should create some overlays where images should be placed. This images must be in a specific position.    When Google Maps api was implemented, they used the method "getBounds" and once there, you can access to "getSouthWest" and "getNorthEast" methods.

Technically, I need do the same with openlayer, but I don't know how can I access to similar functions there. The documentation of this is complicated because google shows functions from older versions.

In this moment I have this

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

The last line only returns an array with the whole bounds. I need to know how can I get the "southwest" and "northEast" bounds from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the coordinates of the extent

```
var extentEPSG4326 = ol.proj.transformExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

console.log('Extent is an array of numbers with the following order: [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]', extentEPSG4326);
```

So to get the southwest coordinates,

```
console.log('SouthWest', [extentEPSG4326[1], extentEPSG4326[0]])
```

So to get the northeast coordinates,

```
console.log('NorthEast', [extentEPSG4326[3], extentEPSG4326[2]])
```